# Vim R Plugin broken after OS X Mountain Lion Upgrade

Tags: macos, r, vim, vi

After upgrading OS X from Lion to Mountain Lion, I receive the following warning whenever I open an R file:

```
Please, set the variable 'g:vimrplugin_term_cmd' in your .vimrc.^@Read the plugin documentation for details.
```

Any idea why this doesn't work? What's changes in Lion to make the plugin OS X not be able to find Terminal?

Comment: Looks like Jakson has updated vimr to use Terminal. You can also solve the issue by upgrading to his latest version. See https://github.com/jcfaria/Vim-R-plugin/issues/14 for details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After looking at the R Vim plugin documentation, it seems that the default values for vimrplugin_term on OS X are not the same as those in Mountain Lion.

Adding the following line to your .vimrc should solve the problem:

```
let vimrplugin_term = "/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal"
```